# htaccess problem

Tags: .htaccess, htpasswd

I seem to be having a problem with my htaccess file.  Here is the code

```
AuthUserFile /core/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Basically what happens is that it asks for the password, you put it in and it launches into an infinite redirect.  This eventually times out and the connection is reset.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont need groups, you should simply remove the "AuthGroupFile" directive. 
The path /dev/null points to a device and the stream "never ends". Any process will infinitly read the ressource, hence the timeout.